# Using Cypress with Typescript gives me a type error for "get" in the example in the docs JQuery not defined

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm trying to setup Typescript with Cypress following the docs found here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfig-json

- I already have `typescript` installed for my server/app.
- I add a `tsconfig.json` in the `cypress/` directory

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

- I add their code in `cypress/support/index.ts`:

```js
// in cypress/support/index.ts
// load type definitions that come with Cypress module
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      /**
       * Custom command to select DOM element by data-cy attribute.
       * @example cy.dataCy('greeting')
       */
      dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>
    }
  } 
}
```

- I add THEIR example command in my `commands.ts` folder, instead of the `same file as above.

```js
// cypress/support/commands.ts (instead of index.tx)
Cypress.Commands.add('dataCy', (value) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-cy=${value}]`)
})
```

The callback function gives me the following error:

```
Argument of type '(value: string) => Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string) => Chainable<Element>'.
```

So I update the `index.ts` callback function

- From `dataCy(value: string): Chainable<Element>`
- To `dataCy(value: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>`

But now my `index.ts` has the following error:

```
'JQuery' is not defined.
```

And I cannot find anywhere/anyway to import JQuery to remove the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? Stuck with this one myself

Comment: This may possibly be the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72755822/3113377

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the return type to `Cypress.JQuery<HTMLElement>` rather than `Chainable<Element>`