# Cypress TypeError: 'JQuery' is not defined

Tags: typescript, cypress

In `cypress/commands.ts` trying to get the type `JQuery` but it returns an eslint error in `VSCode`

```
'JQuery' is not defined.eslint[no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef)
```

[image: JQuery is not defined]

`JQuery` definitely seems to exist as you can see from the screenshot above, but perhaps because there are 2 definitions of the same type there's a conflict?

### command.ts

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      getElByAttr(attr: string, val: string): Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>;
      getByTestId(testId: string, length?: number): Chainable<void>;
    }
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('getByTestId', (testId, length = 1) => {
  cy.get(`[data-testid="${testId}"]`).should('have.length', length);
});

Cypress.Commands.add('getElByAttr', (attr = 'name', val) => {
  return cy.get(`[${attr}=${val}]`);
});

export {};
```

### root tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "babel.config.js", "jest.config.js", "__tests__/**/*.js"]
}
```

I have tried to add a `tsconfig.json` into my `/cypress` folder but that didn't resolve the issue, this is what I tried.

### /cypress/tsonfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress", "node"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

I've tried restarting my TS server in VSCode every time I make any change, but nothing seems to have resolved the issue

It looks like someone else also had this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70249876/3113377)

Also tried adding `"types": ["cypress"]` into either `tsconfig.json`

FWIW I've also tried the following;

- [What is in the docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/typescript-support#Configure-tsconfig-json)
- [This](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1152#issuecomment-355794417)
- [And this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1152#issuecomment-359837094)
- [And this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1236#issuecomment-374935739)
- [And this in both tsconfig files](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1152#issuecomment-374854979)

#### Cypress Version

10.1.0

Truthfully, at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So found the solution was with my eslint.

I needed to add the following to my `extends` options in my `.eslintrc` file

```
'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
```

And had to add the following to my `rules` option

```
'@typescript-eslint/no-namespace': ['error', { allowDeclarations: true }],
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me was to add `/* global JQuery */` at the top of the typescript file where JQuery is used.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer but it helps to avoid using the 'JQuery' interface completely so you won't encounter the error at all. So the suggestion is to use `ReturnType` to infer the type instead of declaring it directly:

```
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      getElByAttr(attr: string, val: string): ReturnType<typeof cy.get>;
      getByTestId(testId: string, length?: number): ReturnType<typeof cy.get>;
    }
  }
}
```